# Clojure - User implementation of Filter

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, lisp

I am a newcomer to Clojure and one of the challenges suggested is a user-implementation of the Filter function.

So I came up with this

```
 (defn filterr
  "Filter implementation"
  [condition coll]
  (if-not (empty? coll)
    (if (condition (first coll))
      (cons (first coll) (filterr condition (rest coll)))
      (filterr (condition (rest coll))))))
(defn -main
  "Main" []
  (t/is (=
         (filterr #(> % 2) [1 2 3 4 5 6])
         [3 4 5 6])
        "Failed basic test"))
```

However, my test fails with the error

`ERROR in () (Numbers.java:229)
Failed basic test
expected: (= (filterr (fn* [p1__42#] (> p1__42# 2)) [1 2 3 4 5 6])
 [3 4 5 6])`

It seems like the function isn't being evaluated fully.

I don't see what I'm doing wrong, and would really appreciate some help on the matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there's an extra set of ( ) in the then clause of the if statement.

```
(filterr (condition (rest coll)))
```

vs

```
(filterr condition (rest coll))
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is in this line `(filterr (condition (rest coll))))))`

You ought to have `(filterr condition (rest coll)))))` instead. Because `(condition (rest coll))` make it a function call, while you simply need to pass this parameter to the next filterr call.